# Zendframework update query not working

Tags: zend-framework

I am not able to find why my query is not working

```
 $data['active']=1
 $bind=$this->_db->quoteInto('id = ?', $id);
 $returnval= $this->_db->update($this->_name,$data,$bind);

`UPDATE `discount_rule` SET `isActive` = ? WHERE (rule_id = 20)`
```

why "?" !. I had tried many way but I am not able to make it in this way.$this_db is type Zend_DB_Adapter_abstract. either it's silly mistake or I am not able to understand how to use Zend_Db_Table_Abstract - update() !.

More details

```
class demo_Model_price extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{
      public function update($data,$id){
        $where='id ='.$id; //i changed it to see if this work 
        try{
           $returnval= $this->update($this->_name,$data,$where);
           return $returnval;
        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
     }
}
```

Can someone identify whats wrong in my query. It's a simple query and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are using `Models`

Some general points

Always start a class in caps `Demo_Model_price`

`update` is a function thats a keyword of `zend`

Try the code below

```
class Demo_Model_price extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{
      public function updateData($data,$id){
        $where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?',$id);
        try{
           $returnval= $this->update($data,$where);
           return $returnval;
        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
     }
```

}

Comment: please check my model class. I am not able to understand why "?" is coming in update query!...any idea

Comment: done !. I changed it to updateData and it is working now for me...Zend is strict with names..